# exportObject and createRegistry same (port + ip)

Tags: java, rmi

```
 RMI exportObject(Remote obj, PORT); 
 createRegistry(PORT);
```

They could share one same port and it works properly. But whenever I try to specify an ip addr for  anyone of them by extending RMISocketFactory, it will report `"port already in use"`.

```
createRegistry(PORT,ssf,csf);
```

If they could share same port on localhost why specific ip doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because they can only share the same port if they are using the same RMIServerSocketFactory, by which I mean that the equals() method of that socket factory returns true when called with the other instance, or itself if you're only using one instance.

So:

1. Don't extend RMISocketFactory, it is obsolete. Create your own class that implements RMIServerSocketFactory, and make sure its equals() method matches itself.
2. Use that server socket factory both in exportObject() and in createRegistry().

But I would question why you're binding to a specific IP address at all. Usually this a mistake and often the wrong solution to another problem, e.g. the java.rmi.server.hostname problem.

Comment: a)Thanks for your reply. I did implemented "InetAddressBoundSocketFactory extends RMISocketFactory implements Serializable { createServerSocket;createSocket; }".By point 1 I guess you advise me to implement "equal()" too.

Comment: b)My purpose is starting multiple app on a multi NIC box, one IP for each instance. I have already set the java.rmi.server.hostname to the IP addr I try to bind to, does that means it's OK to binding specific IP ?

Comment: (A) My point 1 seems perfectly clear to me, and it doesn't coincide with your guess. Try again. NB RMIServerSocketFactory implementations don't need to be Serializable. (B) I don't understand your question.